# F# type mismatch

Tags: f#

I am converting a program from Haskell to F#. Having trouble accessing the Haskell Library in .Net.

What is wrong with this declaration?

```
type Product = string


type Shopping = Product list

let p_tea = "Tea"
let p_sugar = "Sugar"
let p_coffee = "Coffee"
let p_biscuit = "Biscuit"
let p_milk = "Milk"
let p_soya = "Soya"

let shopping = [p_tea,p_sugar,p_coffee,p_biscuit,p_milk]
```

I get the following error.. Similar declaration works in Haskell.. !!

```
Type mismatch. Expecting a
    Shopping    
but given a
    (string * string * string * string * string) list
```

Comment: That looks like a list of tuples. Probably you want to use ; as a separator.

Comment: Side note, more idiomatic F# would be `type Product = |Product of string`.  Type aliases are relatively uncommon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

F# uses commas to separate elements in a tuple, and semicolons to separate elements in a collection. You want:

```
let shopping = [p_tea; p_sugar; p_coffee; p_biscuit; p_milk]
```

Answer (score 0):

In F# list (and array) items are separated by a semicolon. Tuples are separated by commas.

```
type Product = string

type Shopping = Product list

let p_tea = "Tea"
let p_sugar = "Sugar"
let p_coffee = "Coffee"
let p_biscuit = "Biscuit"
let p_milk = "Milk"
let p_soya = "Soya"

let shopping = [p_tea; p_sugar; p_coffee; p_biscuit; p_milk]
```